# the Error "Connection string not found in application config file" occurs EF 6.1.1, even though it is in the Web Config for the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, wcf

I have a WCF service base on the .net framework 4.5.1 that uses several DLLs built around the EntityFramework 6.1.1 , I use them in multiple web sites and web services, but it seems that suddenly all new WCF projects I create cannot find the connection strings. The error is
"No connection string named 'MemberEntities' could be found in the application config file." Connection string name 'MemberEntities' will of course vary depending on what model I am trying to access.

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CoachingEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CoachingModel.csdl|res://*/CoachingModel.ssdl|res://*/CoachingModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SomeServer.com;initial catalog=CoachDB;persist security info=True;user id=SomeUser;password=SomePasswd;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    <add name="MemberEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MemberModel.csdl|res://*/MemberModel.ssdl|res://*/MemberModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SomeServer.com;initial catalog=MembersDB;persist security info=True;user id=SomeUser;password=SomePasswd;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    <add name="QuestionnaireEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/QuestionnaireModel.csdl|res://*/QuestionnaireModel.ssdl|res://*/QuestionnaireModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SomeServer.com;initial catalog=QuestionnaireDB;persist security info=True;user id=SomeUser;password=SomePasswd;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

All of the connection strings have been added to the web config (as shown) for the WCF project just as I have added it to all of the Asp.Net web forms applications in the past, all of which work fine. I have created new clean solutions multiple times and they all have the same problem.

I have previously done the same with WCF web services. Is there some new requirement or something else that I could be missing?  I have seen this error before but copying the connection string from the Class project’s app config to the WCF or Website’s web.config has always solved the problem until now.

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Pro on Windows 8.1

Comment: Does each of the new WCF projects have its own web.config?

Comment: that's weird.  What happens if you grab it yourself? `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MemberEntities"].ConnectionString`

Comment: can you show the code behind that you are using to access the Config Settings also are you adding a reference to the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` in the new projects..?

Comment: Try copying the connection strings into the web.config files of the projects.